# Zend Framework 2 : Ajax submission and Annotation Builder?

Tags: php, zend-framework, annotations, zend-framework2

I want to validate a form that i submit via Ajax but this doesn't work for me. Please help to solve this.

In My annotation builder I used :

```
<?php

    namespace Application\Model;

    use Zend\Form\Annotation;

    /**
     * @Annotation\Name("sejour")
     * @Annotation\Hydrator("Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ObjectProperty")
    */

  class Sejour {

public $id;

/**
 * @Annotation\Validator({"name":"StringLength", "options":{"min":1, "max":3}})
 */
public $titre;

public $agenceId;

public $agenceLibelle;

public function exchangeArray($data)
{
    $this->id = (isset($data['id'])) ? $data['id'] : null;
    $this->titre = (isset($data['titre'])) ? $data['titre'] : null;
    $this->agenceId = (isset($data['agenceId'])) ? $data['agenceId'] : null;
    $this->agenceLibelle = (isset($data['agenceLibelle'])) ? $data['agenceLibelle'] : null;
}
}
```

In my controller file:

```
$values = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$builder    = new AnnotationBuilder();
$entity     = new Sejour();

$form       = $builder->createForm($entity);
$form->bind($entity);
$form->setData($values);

if ( $form->isValid()) {     
    /* save datas in base */    
}else{
    $errors = $form->getMessages();

    print_r($errors);
}
```

Each time i got no errors

Please help me

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is very good example.

http://samsonasik.wordpress.com/2012/10/11/zend-framework-2-using-zend-form-and-ajax/

Try this

Comment: Really dont understand, it's always returning true !

Comment: follow the example ,add the paths properly in jquery.try to send some dummy json data for test.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your Zend Framework 2 version you may have hit the fact that preferFormInputFilter flag has changed it's default value in zf2 2.2.4.

The flag regulates the behavior of the form deciding if, during validation, the form should use its own input filters (that you have beforehand provided) or those provided by each element.

The default for forms created with AnnotationBuilder is to set the flag to true and so, since you have pasted no code where you actually set a filter, the default filter is none.

You may want to enable default element filters for the elements you added by adding:

```
$form->setPreferFormInputFilter(FALSE);
```

just after you create the form.

Another option would naturally be to provide actual input filters to the form.